# Magento issue while overriding a Model

Tags: magento

There is a module under community code pool. Inside the module there is a below model class;

```
class Abc_AbcShipping_Model_Carrier_Abs
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{}
```

I need to override this class in my custom module which is under local code pool. I tried below way to do this;

config.xml

```
<global>
            <models>
                <test>
                    <class>Test_One_Model</class>
                </test>
                <test>
                    <rewrite>
                        <carrier_abs>Test_One_Model_Carrier_Abs</carrier_abs>
                    </rewrite>
                </test>
            </models>
</global>
```

Overridden class
class Test_One_Model_Carrier_Abs
    extends Abc_AbcShipping_Model_Carrier_Abs
{}

But this did not work. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
Thank You so much.

Comment: Have a look at the config.xml from the `Abc_AbcShipping` module and check the name below the `<models>` tag. I think it would be `<models><abcshipping>` not `<models><test>` like in your XML.

Comment: I made this change. But it is not working :(